# Outline or fold mode for editing Emacs Lisp code

Tags: emacs, elisp, folding

Is there a minor mode that I can use in combination with Emacs-Lisp mode such that each function definition can be switched on or off easily without inserting special code in the text file?

for instance

```
(defun test1()
  (message "Hi!"))

(defun test2()
  (message "Bye"))
```

Pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> will fold each function definition into the top line/header as

```
+ (defun test1()
+ (defun test2()
```

Pressing the `+` sign in front will unfold a given function and make it editable..
Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> will unfold all definitions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my setup:

```
(require 'hideshow)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-h") 'hs-toggle-hiding)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2> h h") 'hs-hide-all)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2> h j") 'hs-show-all)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems also to work fine. It looks similar to `outline-minor-mode`. What is actually the difference between `hs-minor-mode` and `outline-minor-mode`?

Answer (score 2):

`outline-minor-mode` does that. Look into its menu.
Instead of the `+`-sign you get the typical ellipsis `...`. That should not hurt. You can do the key-bindings for yourself. (I know that you are clever enough!)

Comment: Thanks! After hiding everything with `C-c @ C-t`, how do you expand one particular function def? I tried `C-c @ <tab>` but I cannot get it to work..

Comment: Outline-> show entry bound to `C-c @ C-e`. That is a binding!

Comment: You can use `reveal-mode` so that moving the cursor into the hidden text will automatically unhide ("reveal") it.

Comment: Apart from `C-c @ C-e` (which shows an entry), one can also use `C-c @ C-s` for this (which shows the whole subtree).

Answer (score 1):

[outshine](https://github.com/tj64/outshine) is a variation of `outline-minor-mode` that lets you use `org-mode` syntax, which is more powerful than the ordinary `outline-mode`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting.. I have downloaded it. But where can I find information about which keybindings are available?

Comment: If you are already using the mode, you can get the bindings with C-m or C-b. If not, they are in the source of outshine.el, around line 1500.

Comment: I tried `C-m` and `C-b` and they do not work. (Seems to be bound to `newline` and `backward-char`). Are any equivalent command to  `C-c @ C-M-h` in `hs-minor-mode`?

Comment: Agh, typo! I meant `C-h m` and `C-h b`, sorry! They are the `describe-mode` and `describe-bindings` commands respectively.

Comment: Ok, thanks, `C-h b` works.. I tried now with the following simple file `t.el`: `(defun test () (message "ok"))` and positioned the cursor inside the definition and then typed `C-c @ C-c` to run `hide-entry` but it only gives the message `before first heading` in the echo area..